# Unity3d Admob integration breaks Android Build: "D8: Program type already present: android.support.customtabs.ICustomTabsCallback"

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, admob, android-support-library

I am developing an Android Game and for a week now, I have tried my best to implement AdMob with Mediation. It works fine in the Editor, but when I build, it throws the error mentioned below. I did try to implement multiple other plugins and they built successfully, but crashed on launch (also tried with just their sample app implementations in new projects).

After a lot of digging around, I have a hypothesis that Facebook needs some aars that Admob need, but cannot use the latest version of it (I have tried latest FB SDK versions to no avail as well). Here are some things I noticed:

1. Notice that CustomTabs is present here. I tried deleting these classes but then build failed with another error

   > Some conflicting dependencies were found.
   >   The following dependency versions were modified:
   >   com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.3.1 --> com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.0.2@aar
   >   com.android.support:cardview-v7:25.3.1 --> com.android.support:cardview-v7:27.0.2@aar
   >   com.android.support:customtabs:25.3.1 --> com.android.support:customtabs:27.0.2@aar
   >   com.android.support:support-v4:25.3.1 --> com.android.support:support-v4:27.0.2@aar
2. This is the AndroidResolverDependencies.xml file in ProjectSettings Dir.

   com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.3.1
       com.android.support:cardview-v7:25.3.1
       com.android.support:customtabs:25.3.1
       com.android.support:support-v4:25.3.1
       com.facebook.android:facebook-core:[5,6)
       com.facebook.android:facebook-login:[5,6)
       com.facebook.android:facebook-share:[5,6)
       com.google.ads.mediation:unity:3.1.0.0
       com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:18.0.0
       com.parse.bolts:bolts-android:1.4.0
       com.unity3d.ads:unity-ads:3.1.0
     

           Assets/Plugins/Android/android.arch.core.common-1.0.0.jar
           Assets/Plugins/Android/android.arch.lifecycle.common-1.0.3.jar
           Assets/Plugins/Android/android.arch.lifecycle.runtime-1.0.3.aar
           Assets/Plugins/Android/androidx.annotation.annotation-1.0.0.jar
           Assets/Plugins/Android/androidx.arch.core.core-common-2.0.0.jar
           Assets/Plugins/Android/androidx.arch.core.core-runtime-2.0.0.aar 
   Assets/Plugins/Android/androidx.asynclayoutinflater.asynclayoutinflater-1.0.0.aar
       Assets/Plugins/Android/androidx.browser.browser-1.0.0.aar
       Assets/Plugins/Android/androidx.collection.collection-1.0.0.jar
       Assets/Plugins/Android/androidx.coordinatorlayout.coordinatorlayout-1.0.0.aar
       Assets/Plugins/Android/androidx.core.core-1.0.0.aar
       Assets/Plugins/Android/androidx.cursoradapter.cursoradapter-1.0.0.aar
       Assets/Plugins/Android/androidx.customview.customview-1.0.0.aar
       Assets/Plugins/Android/androidx.documentfile.documentfile-1.0.0.aar
           Assets/Plugins/Android/androidx.drawerlayout.drawerlayout-1.0.0.aar
           Assets/Plugins/Android/androidx.fragment.fragment-1.0.0.aar
           Assets/Plugins/Android/androidx.interpolator.interpolator-1.0.0.aar
           Assets/Plugins/Android/androidx.legacy.legacy-support-core-ui-1.0.0.aar
           Assets/Plugins/Android/androidx.legacy.legacy-support-core-utils-1.0.0.aar
           Assets/Plugins/Android/androidx.lifecycle.lifecycle-common-2.0.0.jar
           Assets/Plugins/Android/androidx.lifecycle.lifecycle-livedata-2.0.0.aar
           Assets/Plugins/Android/androidx.lifecycle.lifecycle-livedata-core-2.0.0.aar
           Assets/Plugins/Android/androidx.lifecycle.lifecycle-runtime-2.0.0.aar
           Assets/Plugins/Android/androidx.lifecycle.lifecycle-viewmodel-2.0.0.aar
           Assets/Plugins/Android/androidx.loader.loader-1.0.0.aar
   Assets/Plugins/Android/androidx.localbroadcastmanager.localbroadcastmanager-1.0.0.aar
       Assets/Plugins/Android/androidx.print.print-1.0.0.aar
       Assets/Plugins/Android/androidx.slidingpanelayout.slidingpanelayout-1.0.0.aar
       Assets/Plugins/Android/androidx.swiperefreshlayout.swiperefreshlayout-1.0.0.aar
       Assets/Plugins/Android/androidx.versionedparcelable.versionedparcelable-1.0.0.aar
       Assets/Plugins/Android/androidx.viewpager.viewpager-1.0.0.aar
       Assets/Plugins/Android/com.android.support.animated-vector-drawable-27.0.2.aar
   Assets/Plugins/Android/com.android.support.appcompat-v7-27.0.2.aar
       Assets/Plugins/Android/com.android.support.cardview-v7-27.0.2.aar
       Assets/Plugins/Android/com.android.support.customtabs-27.0.2.aar
       Assets/Plugins/Android/com.android.support.support-annotations-27.0.2.jar
       Assets/Plugins/Android/com.android.support.support-compat-27.0.2.aar
       Assets/Plugins/Android/com.android.support.support-core-ui-27.0.2.aar
       Assets/Plugins/Android/com.android.support.support-core-utils-27.0.2.aar
       Assets/Plugins/Android/com.android.support.support-fragment-27.0.2.aar
       Assets/Plugins/Android/com.android.support.support-media-compat-27.0.2.aar
         Assets/Plugins/Android/com.android.support.support-v4-27.0.2.aar
           Assets/Plugins/Android/com.android.support.support-vector-drawable-27.0.2.aar
           Assets/Plugins/Android/com.facebook.android.facebook-common-5.1.0.aar
           Assets/Plugins/Android/com.facebook.android.facebook-core-5.1.0.aar
           Assets/Plugins/Android/com.facebook.android.facebook-login-5.1.0.aar
           Assets/Plugins/Android/com.facebook.android.facebook-share-5.1.0.aar
           Assets/Plugins/Android/com.google.ads.mediation.unity-3.1.0.0.aar
           Assets/Plugins/Android/com.google.android.gms.play-services-ads-18.0.0.aar
           Assets/Plugins/Android/com.google.android.gms.play-services-ads-base-18.0.0.aar
         Assets/Plugins/Android/com.google.android.gms.play-services-ads-identifier-17.0.0.aar
               Assets/Plugins/Android/com.google.android.gms.play-services-ads-lite-18.0.0.aar
               Assets/Plugins/Android/com.google.android.gms.play-services-basement-17.0.0.aar
               Assets/Plugins/Android/com.google.android.gms.play-services-gass-18.0.0.aar
               Assets/Plugins/Android/com.google.android.gms.play-services-measurement-base-17.0.0.aar
               Assets/Plugins/Android/com.google.android.gms.play-services-measurement-sdk-api-17.0.0.aar
               Assets/Plugins/Android/com.google.zxing.core-3.3.3.jar
               Assets/Plugins/Android/com.parse.bolts.bolts-android-1.4.0.jar
               Assets/Plugins/Android/com.parse.bolts.bolts-applinks-1.4.0.jar
               Assets/Plugins/Android/com.parse.bolts.bolts-tasks-1.4.0.jar
               Assets/Plugins/Android/com.unity3d.ads.unity-ads-3.1.0.aar

   ```
     <settings>
       <setting name="androidAbis" value="armeabi-v7a,x86" />
       <setting name="bundleId" value="com.pratyaksh.cosmicballs" />
       <setting name="explodeAars" value="True" />
       <setting name="gradleBuildEnabled" value="True" />
       <setting name="gradleTemplateEnabled" value="False" />
       <setting name="installAndroidPackages" value="True" />
       <setting name="packageDir" value="Assets\Plugins\Android" />
       <setting name="patchAndroidManifest" value="True" />
       <setting name="patchMainTemplateGradle" value="True" />
       <setting name="projectExportEnabled" value="False" />
       <setting name="useJetifier" value="False" />
     </settings>
   </dependencies>
   ```
3. Smaller Portions from error log

   > CommandInvokationFailure: Gradle build failed. 
   >   E:\UnityEditor\2019.1.0f2\Editor\Data\PlaybackEngines\AndroidPlayer/Tools\OpenJDK\Windows\bin\java.exe -classpath "E:\UnityEditor\2019.1.0f2\Editor\Data\PlaybackEngines\AndroidPlayer\Tools\gradle\lib\gradle-launcher-4.6.jar" org.gradle.launcher.GradleMain "-Dorg.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx4096m" "assembleRelease"
   >   stderr[
   >   D8: Program type already present: android.support.customtabs.ICustomTabsCallback
   >   FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
   >
   > - What went wrong:
   >     Execution failed for task ':transformDexArchiveWithExternalLibsDexMergerForRelease'.
   >     com.android.builder.dexing.DexArchiveMergerException: Error while merging dex archives:

.
.
//SHORTENED FOR STACKOVERFLOW
.
.
.

> :transformClassesWithDexBuilderForRelease
>   C:\Users\TehBlindNutSack.gradle\caches\transforms-1\files-1.1\facebook-android-wrapper-7.17.0.aar\4bb1132b85935d425bf3b80edd9162a8\jars\classes.jar: D8: Interface `com.facebook.applinks.AppLinkData$CompletionHandler` not found. It's needed to make sure desugaring of `com.facebook.unity.FB$2` is correct. Desugaring will assume that this interface has no default method.
>   `C:\Users\TehBlindNutSack\.gradle\caches\transforms-1\files-1.1\facebook-android-wrapper-7.17.0.aar\4bb1132b85935d425bf3b80edd9162a8\jars\classes.jar: D8: Type`com.facebook.applinks.AppLinkData`was not found, it is required for default or static interface methods desugaring of`void com.facebook.unity.FB.FetchDeferredAppLinkData(java.lang.String)`
>   :transformDexArchiveWithExternalLibsDexMergerForRelease FAILED

Please, if someone could help me get it right, it would mean a world to me.
Sorry for bad formatting.

Edit: Steps to reproduce: 
1. Create a new Unity(2019.1.0f2) Project with android build support
2. Add FB SDK
3. add GoogleMobileAds SDK
4. Build

Comment: Have you checked compatibility between SDK version and sdk version of android that you want to build?

Comment: I do believe I have. But to be doubly sure, how do I check all the packages' android api compatibility (if that is what you mean).

Comment: I guess there 'AnidroidManifest.xml' for Admob and minimum and maximum version for that. After you see that version, you need to see Android BuildSettings in Unity, there is menu for android sdk version setting, I think you might know already. be sure

Comment: Thank you, but I already tried that. Could you confirm if this error occurs for you as well? Steps to reproduce: 1. Create a new Unity Project with android build support, 2. Add FB SDK, 3. add GoogleMobileAds SDK, 4. Build.

Comment: Ok, I will try it soon. Which Unity version do you use?

Comment: 2019.1.0f2  THANK YOU for taking the time.

Comment: It takes times so I will get back to you with response what i have after test it

Comment: anything, Brian?

Comment: I've tested build 2019.1 failed but 2019.1.2 succeed so I think I should see deeply but technically working in company now so will see soon. almost done for jobs

Comment: okay.. I'll try 2019.2

Comment: still watching it in 2019.1.0f2 and I succeed on 2019.1.2f1 not 2019.2

Comment: I tested with only facebook sdk on 2019.1.0f2 and failed.

Comment: I'll install 2019.1.8f1 and keep you posted.

Comment: 2019.1.8f1 did not work out. Now trying 2019.2.b

Comment: when I found, I will let you know, I'm on it

Answer (score 1):

When you're using GooglePlayResolver you'll be getting new **androidx.** files. Which could be in conflict with **com.android.support.** files

Try to do this:

```
Assets -> GooglePlayResolver -> Android Resolver -> Settings -> Set Jetiffier On
Force Resolve.
```

Be sure to use the latest:
https://github.com/googlesamples/unity-jar-resolver/releases/tag/v1.2.121

Check this discussion for more info. 
https://github.com/googlesamples/unity-jar-resolver/issues/145

Comment: Will Try. Thanks

Comment: Maxim, your solution worked. Thank you. TIL I need to read documentations

Answer (score 0):

[image]

I found solutions. there are library files duplicates, see directory and see library files make it as I did. Android and iOS library should be set for each platform.

1. Download SDK from "https://developers.facebook.com/docs/unity/"
2. Open SDK directory. there are duplicates. So make a library for each platform.
3. Set proper platform for iOS and Android.

It works and I tested on Unity 2019.1.0f2. facebookSDK has problem with compile. they made trap.

Answer (score 0):

I have a good news and a bad news.

Bad news First: None of the above solutions worked for me.

Good News: I installed 2019.1.08f and it threw the same error, but with a longer log. I went through the log and found the exact files causing the collision: androidx.browser.browser-1.0.0.aar and androidx.core.core-1.0.0.aar.
I just went into them, opened Classes.jar and deleted Android directory in both the aars' jars.

Build and Run...Voila. (At least for now).

Will update here if another issue arises.

Thank you Brian, for Taking the time to test it and answering the question.